# How do I determine U-boot entry point?

Tags: embedded-linux, xilinx, u-boot

How do I determine from what address in flash the current u-boot image has booted from? This is with the focus to determine if the fallback u-boot image has been used.

Comment: Why you need such low level of identifying the fallback bootloader. You could also "hardcode" a linux boot argument like `boot=fallback` into your fallback bootloader and then draw it from `/proc/cmdline`.

Comment: AFAIK there is no convention for parameter passing between a bootstrap and U-Boot (as there is for the Linux kernel).  You will probably have to devise your own scheme using a register and/or memory buffer.  This assumes that whatever information that was used to determine which image to use is no longer available to U-Boot.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in C, rather than scripting at the prompt, you can look around in 'gd' and 'relocaddr' and 'reloc_off' to work out where things started off at.